# Why does Windows flag VB6 EXEs with 'SETUP' in their name to run as administrator?

Tags: windows, vb6

I've been mucking around in VB6 forever and I never before realized that all the programs I compile with 'SETUP' in their name have the little 'run as admin' shield on their EXE icons. Sure enough Windows runs them with admin or at least elevated privileges. This doesn't happen with .NET applications. It's a problem for me now because our software has a 'main menu' program that launches all the other programs (hundreds of them) and it uses an ActiveX DLL to communicate with all of them. Apparently this communication 'breaks' when the two programs communicating have different privileges. Our customers are becoming more concerned with security and do not want the main menu program having admin rights.

Does anyone know how this works and if there may be a registry setting or something to turn it off? Thanks.

Comment: [UAC: Installer detection technology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works#installer-detection-technology)

Comment: Thanks Damien_The_Unbeliever. If you want to make that an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: Windows has worked this way since 2006 when Vista came out.  It is appcompat applied to legacy code.  A proper manifest with a `trustInfo` section will avoid this appcompat shim being applied.

Comment: Thanks Bob77. I found a site that shows how to do this and will give it a try. http://www.restuner.com/howto-insert-trust-info-manifest.htm